# Non-grouping field used in HAVING clause with sub query

Tags: mysql, group-by, mariadb

On MariaDB with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option enabled, I am getting the error

> Non-grouping field 'vcount' is used in HAVING clause

when executing the query

```
SELECT c.* FROM 
automobile_company c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) AS vcount FROM automobile_variant GROUP BY company_id) vc
USING (company_id) 
WHERE c.automobile_type = 0 AND vc.vcount > 0;
```

But the query does not even have a `HAVING` clause.

- Is it because MariaDB is rewriting the query for optimization?
- Is it possible to rewrite the above query without moving the GROUP BY outside the sub query?
- Is my only option to use a simple LEFT OUTER JOIN without sub query, and mention every field that needs to be selected in the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: It looks like a bug in a new optimization in 10.2 (which you are apparently using). As a workaround, try to set `optimizer_switch='condition_pushdown_for_derived=off'`. Please file a bug report at https://jira.mariadb.org.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to check if a row exists in the automobile_variant, you don't need a count or a group by

```
    SELECT c.* FROM automobile_company c WHERE c.automobile_type = 0 AND 
    EXISTS(select company_id from automobile_variant av where av.company_id=c.company_id);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am more interested in the full solution, rather than this single instance.